# MVC: Binding CKEditor textarea value to the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, ckeditor

I have chosen CKEditor as the Rich Text Editor component for my ASP.Net MVC project.

To render the Rich Text Editor is not a problem (quite easy in fact):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.MessageDiffusion.Message, new { @id = idRichTextEditor })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // Rich Text Editor (CKEditor) Configuration 
        CKEDITOR.replace(
            idRichTextEditor, {
                language: 'fr'
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Which renders:

[image: RichTextArea correctly rendering my Model.MessageDiffusion.Message property]

My problem is related with posting the data. If I change the message to: 'The new message' I will still get 'The old message' on my post:

[image: The controller's HttpPost action]

I mean, the viewModel will have a property message which will contain 'The old message' instead of 'The new message'.
I've tried to do the following immediately before the post (onBegin):

```
  $('#idRichTextEditor').text(CKEDITOR.instances["idRichTextEditor"].getData());
```

Or:

$('#idRichTextEditor').val(CKEDITOR.instances["idRichTextEditor"].getData());

Which didn't help... I've also tried:

```
for (var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances["idRichTextEditor"].updateElement();
}
```

But I seem to be unable to bind the CKEditor's text area with my model. I would like to state that if I turn this rich text area into a common text area I can easily get 'The new message' on the controller side.

I would like to state that despite interesting, and related to my problem, the following stackoverflow's discussions didn't help me much:

[CKEditor MVC 3 implementation Help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333160/ckeditor-mvc-3-implementaion-help-needed)

[CKEditor and ASP.Net MVC 3 RequiredAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491316/ckeditor-and-asp-net-mvc-3-requiredattribute)

I believe the problem might be related with the fact that

*setting data in CKEditor is an asynchronous operation , val( 'some data' ) will return a jQuery Promise object if any of the elements is an editor. You can use it with jQuery helpers:
$.when( $( '#editor' ).val( 'foo' ) ).then( function() {
    // Now you are sure that the data is set.
} );*

I read this information here:
[CKEditor 4 documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery)

**Update**: I just realised that when I post the data a second time, the richtext info is correctly binded to the Message property of my viewmodel. This means that I can get what I want if I click the 'save button' twice, but not once...

Comment: Can you update the question with definition of `ViewModel`?

Comment: Hi @ramiramilu, MessageDiffusion is an entity and the Message property is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I just didn't search well enough on StackOverFlow, which indeed has an answer for everything. The right answer is:

```
$('#YOURFORMID').on('submit', function(){
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
});
```

Which I found here:

[CKEDITOR doesn't submit data via ajax on first submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398225/ckeditor-doesnt-submit-data-via-ajax-on-first-submit)